# Web Hosting STARTER IIS7 sub domain isn't working

Tags: iis-7, subdomain

I have created sub domain, but when am browsing it in a browser it shows an error: "This webpage is not available".

Do I need to add some records in DNS Zone ? Normally in other hostings I haven't met such problem, cause sub domain was working immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to resolve the new domain by `dig` or `nslookup` commangs from server anf from remote workstation. Some times we need to wait aprox. 10 minutes, before dns-cache updates.

Comment: it is already more than 30 minutes that I created sub domain @shcherbak

Comment: did you update zone serial? ones you have old zone serial, the zone will be cached till TTL

Comment: where I can update that pls ? It is the first time that am using IIS7 :( @shcherbak

Comment: if i remember well, right click on root node on DNS-management console, General tab. test your zone by online tool http://network-tools.com/. This toll shows serial number of zone. you can grep https://www.howtoforge.com/troubleshooting-common-dns-misconfiguration-errors for troubleshuting. And dummy question: did you restart the DNS?

Comment: Seems it has just started to show something. That is good for now. But one question server should automatically create folder for subdomain as normal servers do, right? @shcherbak

Comment: or I need to create folder for sub domain myself and write rewrire rules in web.config file? @shcherbak

Comment: depends on webhosting settings. ususly need to create subdomain and folder

Comment: right now I created folder with sub domain name but it shows server default page. Do you have any thoughts how can I override this and show what I have in that folder under the sub domain ? @shcherbak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33035/discussion-between-user3090189-and-shcherbak).